# Is there a simple way to select values from one column depending on anther column in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame below but I need to select rows from each code depending on the canceled and order column.

Say code xxx has orders [6, 1, 5, 1] and the order is 11. I need an algorithm that can select the rows that meet the total 11 say rows with orders [6 & 5], then create a new DataFrame with the corresponding ids and sum of orders per code as below.

If No rows match, then select the closest ids and add it to a list with their difference from the canceled as below 111111 is the selected id and 35 is the diff between 55 and 20. i need an algorithm that can handle 10k Rows

```
     **code**          **canceled**      **order**       **ids**
        xxx                 11.0            13     [128281, 128283]
        cvd                 20             55     [111111, 35]

df = [
    {"code":"xxx","canceled":11.0,"id":"128281","order":6},
    {"code":"xxx","canceled":11.0,"id":"128282","order":1},
    {"code":"xxx","canceled":11.0,"id":"128283","order":5},
    {"code":"xxx","canceled":11.0,"id":"128284","order":1},
    {"code":"xxS","canceled":0.0,"id":"108664","order":4},
    {"code":"xxS","canceled":0.0,"id":"110515","order":1},
    {"code":"xxS","canceled":0.0,"id":"113556","order":1},
    {"code":"eeS","canceled":5.0,"id":"115236","order":1},
    {"code":"eeS","canceled":5.0,"id":"108586","order":1},
    {"code":"eeS","canceled":5.0,"id":"114107","order":1},
    {"code":"eeS","canceled":5.0,"id":"113472","order":3},
    {"code":"eeS","canceled":5.0,"id":"114109","order":3},
    {"code":"544W","canceled":44.0,"id":"107650","order":20},
    {"code":"544W","canceled":44.0,"id":"127763","order":4},
    {"code":"544W","canceled":44.0,"id":"128014","order":20},
    {"code":"544W","canceled":44.0,"id":"132434","order":58},
    {"code":"cvd","canceled":20.0,"id":"11111","order":55}
]
```

I tried a solution from my last project but it's not working, though both solve the same issue, can someone help me out here.

```
from itertools import combinations    
def combs(lst, n):
    return (c for k in range(1, n+1) for c in combinations(lst, k))

def best_match(lst, target, n=20):
    return min(combs(lst, n), key=lambda c: (abs(target - sum(c)), len(c)))

best_match(np.array(df['order']), np.array(df['canceled']))

# sorted Rows
sorted_rows = df.apply(best_match(np.array(CV['order']), np.array(CV['canceled'])))
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why only ids 128281 and 128283, why not 128282 and 128284? Is order 13 the sum of order 6,5,1 and 1, or not?

Comment: @powerPixie,  i selected  [128281 , 128283]  coz their sum is 11 and 13 is the sum for all orders from code xxx, let me hope this is clear now, Your solution will be of great help

Answer (score 1):

Use -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df_g = df.groupby('code').agg({'canceled': 'first', 'order': list})

def get_combo(x):
    ind = x['canceled']
    weight = x['order']
    id_ = x['id']
    cmb = []
    ids = []
    for x in range(1, len(weight) + 1):
        cmb += itertools.combinations(weight, x)
        ids += itertools.combinations(id_, x)
    try:
        indx = [sum(i) for i in cmb].index(ind)
        return (cmb[indx], ids[indx])
    except:
        return ([],[])

t = df_g.apply(get_combo, axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
t.columns = ['combs', 'ids']
df_g = pd.concat([df_g, t[['ids']]], axis=1).drop('id', axis=1).reset_index()
df_g['order'] = df_g['order'].apply(sum)
print(df_g)
```

**Output**

```
   code  canceled  order                       ids
0  544W      44.0    102  (107650, 127763, 128014)
1   cvd      20.0     55                        []
2   eeS       5.0      9  (115236, 108586, 113472)
3   xxS       0.0      6                        []
4   xxx      11.0     13          (128281, 128283)
```

Comment: Hi Vivek  thanks for the quick response but  when i ran this code, i get the below error,
KeyError: ('id', 'occurred at index 544W')

Comment: i see that df_g does not have 'id' column which you are applying the get_combo function

Comment: Hi Vivek thanks for the solution, i managed to  make it work, i updated the below line
df_g = df.groupby('code').agg({'canceled': 'first', 'order': list, 'id':list})

I ran into  another issue i see that  if no match is found, i would like to select the closest id  then add it to the list with with the difference (Negative or Positive)

Comment: Hi Vivek thanks for the solution, i managed to  make it work, i updated the below line
df_g = df.groupby('code').agg({'canceled': 'first', 'order': list, 'id':list})

I ran into  another issue i see that  if no match is found, i would like to select the closest id  then add it to the list with the difference (Negative or Positive)

Say  for cvd (11111, 35)  where 11111 is the id , then 35 is the difference between canceled and order

Comment: Might have had a bug with the id column while I was trying a solution. I think fuzzy match should be handled differently and deserves it's own question :-)

Comment: You should try messing with the except block the the get_combo function to try and implement the nearest cases

Comment: Hi Vivek, the solution fails to run on big data sets even on 100 Rows it throws a MemoryError: occurred at index .....

Fails at this line, cmb += itertools.combinations(weight, x)